# Deserializing JSON with more than 1 attribute

Tags: c#, json, .net-4.0, deserialization

this time I'm trying to deserialize a json response to my request.
The full json can be found here: http://pastebin.com/V0hAxFmj

```
public class Folheto
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("zoom")]
    public string imagem { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("pageCount")]
    public int pageCount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string nome { get; set; }
}
```

The best solution would be have a list of string containing all "zoom" links in the path ["pages][pagenumber][imageUrls].

Am I missing something?

EDIT: JSON CODE

```
{
  "directBrochureUrl": "http://www.ofertia.com/catalogo-305846837",
  "id": 305846837,
  "pageCount": 8,
  "pages": {
    "1": {
      "imageUrls": {
        "normal": "http://static01.ofertia.com/catalogos/84e0a539-f687-4682-b6f8-b29e79f8de87/0/normal.v1.jpg",
        "zoom": "http://static01.ofertia.com/catalogos/84e0a539-f687-4682-b6f8-b29e79f8de87/0/large.v1.jpg",
        "zoomSize": "{1079,1600}"
      },
      "productOverlays": [

      ]
    },

  },
  "poll": {
    "hasPoll": false,
    "hasPollImage": null,
    "mobileLongImage": null,
    "mobileSquareImage": null,
    "pollUrl": null,
    "webImage": null
  },
  "retailerId": 84243242,
  "retailerName": "Dia Market",
  "sector": {
    "iconUrl": "http://static01.ofertia.com/theme/logo-100497.v71.png",
    "id": 100497,

  },
  "showAdsInVisualizer": false,
  "title": "Calidad y precio están muy cerca",
  "validFrom": "2014-09-11T00:00:00",
  "validUntil": "2014-09-24T23:00:00"
}
```

EDIT2 (Request Code):

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.ofertia.com/api/v1/brochure/static/305846837");
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0";
            request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-US,en;q=0.5");
            request.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With", @"XMLHttpRequest");
            request.Referer = "http://www.ofertia.com/catalogo";
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.Accept = "application/json";

            try
            {
                using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
                {
                    var responseValue = string.Empty;
                    // grab the response  
                    using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                        {
                            responseValue = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                    if (responseValue != "")
                    {
                        Folheto jsonModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Folheto>(responseValue);
                        string _id = jsonModel.id;
                        string _nome = jsonModel.nome;
                        string _link_imagem = jsonModel.imagem;
                        int num_pag =jsonModel.pageCount;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                // Handle error
            }
```

Comment: That's a large amount of JSON in your sample. It would really help if you'd provide a *short* but complete program demonstrating the problem, with a small piece of JSON. (It doesn't help that it's not the original JSON, but some oddly-formatted version, too.)

Comment: Sorry didn't find how to format it properly.
The pastebin code is the real full answer I'm trying to read, I just used postman to get a prettier and easier to read version of the answer.

If you know where i can paste it so it's easy and nice to read I will post here in the meantime i can take a screenshot

http://prntscr.com/4pl3ih part1
http://prntscr.com/4pl3s2  part2

Comment: You shouldn't put it in a pastebin at all. You should have a *short* example which can be included directly in the question. All you need is about 20 lines of code and 10 lines of JSON (if that) - we should be able to copy the json into a file (or just include it in the code), copy and paste the code into another file, compile and run. Screenshots really don't help us reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry, was just trying to help putting all the answer, i edited the json answer to contain a bit of the general information, and the properties I want to take values from.

Comment: You *still* haven't provided a short but complete program, and your JSON clearly contains multiple results - what would you *expect* for the value of `zoom`? You should almost certainly have a `Pages` property which is a dictionary of string to `Page`, where `Page` is another class which has a list of image URLs, each of which has a zoom property... Basically, your code doesn't represent the structure of the JSON at all. Your JSON is also either invalid or incomplete, which doesn't help us.

Comment: I seriously don't get what you are telling.
I'm making a request to this page :"http://www.ofertia.com/api/v1/brochure/static/305846837"

I'm getting the answer in the variable posted in the main post responseValue.

There's no way I can paste in here the full answer, as it goes for each page of a pdf (in this case 8 pages)

Like i said in the main post, Would Be great if I could get all the values from "zoom" (each page has 1, making a total of 8 resutls)

for example for page 1 zoom value should be this:http://static01.ofertia.com/catalogos/84e0a539-f687-4682-b6f8-b29e79f8de87/0/large.v1.jpg

Comment: Right, so you want lots of values. How would you expect that to be represented in a single property? Your class structure needs to match the structure of the JSON, unless you query it separately. But you *can* definitely include a valid piece of JSON which demonstrates what you're trying to achieve, which is complete in itself, along with a short but complete console application which shows what you're trying to do. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: Ok all my code is in the post, the json pasted is valid and works to test it according to http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: That's clearly not all your code. It's not got a class declaration, for a start. I give up, I'm afraid. There's only so many times I can describe a short but complete program.

Comment: wth... this is the code running when I click on a button.
There's the class Folheto in the beggining of the post, and the code it runs when i click the button...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a working but not so perfect solution.

First I need to take the property that allows me to know the number of total pages the pdf has:

```
FolhetoOfertia jsonModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FolhetoOfertia>(responseValue);
int num_pag = jsonModel.pageCount;
```

(num_pag is the variable that will let me loop the pages in the next step)

2nd I parse the answer from my request (answer is inside the variable responseValue), and make a loop using the number of the page it is searching, this will work whatever the number of pages is, since I get the actual value and don't need to use a fake high number

```
var jObj = JObject.Parse(responseValue);
for (int pag = 1; pag < num_pag + 1; pag++)
    {
        string valores = jObj["pages"][pag.ToString()]["imageUrls"]["zoom"].ToString();
        lista_links.Add(valores);
    }
```

with this the list I created to have the links I want to take that are inside the property "zoom" will be populated with all pages links for each pdf